# How can I stop a $_POST from producing relative image paths?

Tags: html, php, firefox, google-chrome, wysiwyg

I have an image link that I am running through a WYSIWYG then I sent the html to a page for the user to view before sending the html content as a newsletter. My problem is when I `$_POST` the html code to the new page the browser removes the `http://www.mysite.com/` and leave behind `images/myimage.jpg`.

Can anyone shed light on this?

Comment: Seams to only occur with `SRC` and not `HREF`

Comment: I have found a fix by using the php function `str_replace()` `$mail_body = str_replace("src=\"", "src=\"http://www.mysite.co.uk/", $mail_body);` This works but is not a permanent fix.

Comment: You should try to explain what you are doing. What do you mean with "though a WYSISWG"? mail_body? It is unlikely that your browser is removing something but you have to be more clear.

Comment: It's probably some Javascript editor you are using, which usually should have a setting to preserve the URL's as they are entered.

Comment: I am using the tinyMCE WYSIWYG, once I `_POST` the HTML created from tinyMCE I `echo` this to a normal text file, but it appears that the browser is removing the URL and leaving behind the file paths as you normally see when you view source in any browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using tinymce, look at the [url options](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3aURL) when calling tinyMCE.init

you probably need:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    ...
    convert_urls : false
});
```